# In which writing(s) does Hugo Grotius set forth the "Governmental Theory of the Atonement"?

Tags: soteriology, atonement, resource-request

I'm trying to locate, in book form in English, the writings of Hugo Grotius in relation to the "Governmental View of the Atonement". I see very little of his writings available in book form in English and can't seem to identify any texts that do or would likely contain his writings on this subject. Does anybody know where I can obtain such? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hugo Grotius develops this in *Defensio Fidei Catholicae de Satisfactione Christi*  ("Defense of the Catholic Faith on the Satisfaction of Christ").  An 1889 translation, by Frank Hugh Foster, is available on [yoel.info](http://yoel.info/grotius.pdf).

On Google Books [the work has no preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=oZIpMwEACAAJ), so there we are limited to excerpts published in books on the topic.  For example, in [*Atonement Theories*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IQyQBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA134) by Ben Pugh, Grotius is quoted:

> The end of the matter which is being discussed, as to the intention of God and of Christ, is twofold: the display of the Divine justice; and, so far as we are concerned, the remission of sins, that is, our release from punishment.  For if you take the exaction of penalty impersonally, its end is the display of the Divine justice; but if personally, that is, why Christ is punished, its end is that we may gain release form punishment.

More extensive quotes are available in *Introducing Christian Theologies* by Victor I. Ezigbo, [pages 92–93](https://books.google.com/books?id=V8GqCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA92).

Comment: The brief (but insightful and authoritative) comments of the O'Donovans introducing the Grotius materials [in their reader](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pwoTGSsiqa4C&printsec=frontcover) make some contribution to this theme, I think.